# How much does replacing the screen of iPod touch 4th gen cost in India?

Tags: ipod-touch, ipod, screen, repair

I have an iPod touch 4th generation, 32GB. Broke the screen and since then it doesn't even charge. I am in Hyderabad, India, and I would appreciate a locally available answer.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is primarily a shopping question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try www.irepair.in also avl @ Hyderabad. Original screen replacement costs approx 5k. Apple will replace the product if it's out of warranty for 9.2k.